# SQL concat value as column

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I'm trying to convert one string to a valid column.
As you can see I need to get something like `'mo._olddb_uid_'+nu._olddb_name_db` that should use the column `mo._olddb_uid_001`

How can I achieve this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [PI_CONSOLIDATION].[dbo].[new_unite] nu
  LEFT JOIN [PI_CONSOLIDATION].[dbo].[Motif_Orientation] mo ON CONCAT('mo._olddb_uid_',nu._olddb_name_db) = CONCAT(nu._olddb_name_db,'_',nu.id_motif_orientation)
   WHERE nu.nom_res = 'TEST' and nu.prenom_res = 'Foobar'
```

Thanks

---

EDITED:
I have 18 application each with his DB. Those applications are almost similar with different data but sometimes the data can be found on also on the other sources.
So `[new_unite]` has the id of patient, id_group and the source database

```
id_resident id_groupe_res   _olddb_name_db
728         31              src1
629         21              src6
731         25              src9
934         12              src18
...
```

The other table has some parameters that have identical params but with different IDs depending on the DB of the source.

So the `[Motif_Orientation]` looks like :
[image: Table]

So mainly this query is just only to test if the data is stored correctly on the final application where there is just one DB and all the data merged

```
id_motif_orientation    label
1407                    Famille
1410                    Structures d'hébergement
1422                    Etablissement d'Education Spéciale
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help.

Comment: That isn't how SQL works. A literal string can't be used to replace the name of an object (nor can a variable). `DECLARE @table sysname = N'dbo.MyTable'; SELECT * FROM @table;` won't `SELECT` rows from `dbo.MyTable` it'll give an error about an undeclared table variable `@table`. This seems like what you really have is a poor database design which needs fixing.

Comment: I added the data that is used... and I think that the design is as expected when we are dealing with merge of 18 different databases

Comment: There's your problem then @3pepe3, you *think* that design is correct. You shouldn't have many `*_src` columns, you should have a column `src`, with values like `1`, `2`, `3`, etcetc, etc. Then you would easily be able to do what you need to.

Answer (score 0):

What you could try to do is make a function with the output being the value you want to left join. Your output should be a single value doesn't matter the type. Then, call it as:

```
LEFT JOIN 
    (func_name(param1,param2,...) AS CONCAT(...) FROM DUAL)
ON 1=1
```

The result should be your value left joined to the current table under whatever column name you need. The only problem is that you will need to do this one by one for each row, so it is only really useful for smaller tables. Wish you gave more info so I could give a better answer but this worked for me when I was having a similar issue with renaming a column.